# "Eyeball analysis of data" equivalent japanese word

Tags: translation, word-choice

"Eyeball analysis of data" is sort of a slang phrase to mean the act of plotting a data set and observing its various peaks and slews and understanding its general behaviour.

I would be grateful if someone can tell me the Japanese equivalent of this expression.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The closest one would be:

[目測]{もくそく}

It means the act of measuring with the eye.  *Reference：[英辞郎(dictionary)](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%9B%AE%E6%B8%AC)*

You can use it like this: 目測で線を引く＝draw line by eyeballing it.

It is often used in occasions like "eyeball the distance・height・length・(any measurable quality)" etc.

Practical usage proof(Japanese site)：[米倉研究室 | Yonekura Lab.](http://yard.cis.ibaraki.ac.jp/~yonekura/newpage2.htm)

Comment: Yep I just confirmed I am correct: [link](http://yard.cis.ibaraki.ac.jp/~yonekura/newpage2.htm)

Comment: Can someone tell me why my answer is downvoted?  目測 is definitely the word for it.

Comment: If your problem is with it being a verb (although its the same), I have just  fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I feel like the term 「目視検査」might be applicable here.
If anyone else have a better alternative I would welcome your answers.

Comment: It is usually used in occasions like "check for defects with the eye"

Comment: It CANNOT be used to represent the idea of "getting information through estimation with the eye"

Comment: Its meaning is closer to: "Inspection with the eye"

Comment: Ok I understand your point.